# Using widgets multiple times in QGIS form independently

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield, forms

I am using QGIS to set up a Form to collect data using QField.
The form is to use Containers with similar Widgets such as Date and Photo.

If I use the same Date widget in two separate containers, they are not independent, i.e. they can't be set individually. I need to name one Date-1 and the other Date-2. Likewise, a widget named Notes.
Is there a way to set the widget to function without disturbing the function in another container?

Comment: Thank you, that's what had resorted to. I was wishing there was a switch to use Date, Notes, etc multiple times in a container independently without having to create individual fields

Answer (score 3):

Widgets provide a means to view and edit attribute data (fields). If two widgets point to the same attribute they are not independent. If they do not point to the same attribute they are independent. So you need to ensure your feature class (layer) has the appropriate attributes (fields). From your description I suspect your feature class needs to include attributes "Date-1" and "Date-2". When you add these to your form, whether or not they are in different containers, they will act independently.